# Finding edges in an undirected graph with a specific weight that belong to a minimum spanning tree in linear time

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given an undirected graph $G$, a weight function on its edges and specific weight $X$. I am trying to find all the edges in $G$ with weight $X$ and that belong to some MST of $G$. I am looking for an algorithm that runs in linear time $O(V+E)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that an edge belongs to some MST if and only if it is not the strictly heaviest edge of some cycle. You can check in linear time if an edge belongs to some MST by doing a DFS from an extremity of the edge, only taking edges with a strictly lower weight. If the DFS reaches the other extremity, then the edge does not belong to the MST.

In your case, do a DFS from the extremity of some edge with weight X. If you encounter the extremity of some edge with weight X, mark this extremity (but do not add the edge to your DFS, we only take edges with strictly lower weight). Edges with both extremities marked are not in any MST, edges with only one extremity marked are in some MST. If there are some edges of weight X with extremities not marked, then do another DFS from an extremity (ignore previous markings). Do this until you classified all the edges with weight X.

This is linear because each DFSs are disconnected.